# Where to read about sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-theory

I'm working through Mumford's Red Book, and after introducing the definition of a sheaf, he says "Sheaves are almost standard nowadays, and we will not develop their properties in detail." So I guess I need another source to read about sheafs from. Does anybody know of any expository papers that cover them? I'd prefer to not have to dig deep into a separate textbook if possible.

Comment: Section II.1 of Hartshorne and Chapter 2 of Vakil are both good.

Comment: + Vakil chapter is indeed amazing, he doesn't discuss (quasi-)coherent sheaves though (that's a separate chapter). Hartshorne discusses (quasi)-coherent sheaves on II.5. In both books though you need to get your hands dirty, like never before, and do tons and tons of exercises that they provide.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. One other thing that's usually saved for later is the notion of pullback $f^*$, which again one can find in Hartshorn II.5. I can't remember how much Mumford really needs.

Comment: If you read Hartshorne, you should definitely note that his way of introducing the structure sheaf of an affine scheme is technically flawless, but this is not the way, you should think about a structure sheaf.

Comment: Another reference, maybe a little more lightweight than Hartshorne and Vakil, is Shafarevich, _Basic Algebraic Geometry Volume 2_, Section V.2. (Again this is a textbook, but I don't think you need to "dig deep" to read this part profitably.)

Comment: I first learned sheaves from Kempf's "Algebraic Varieties", and I was pretty satisfied about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand that you don't want to dig deep into a separate text book of Sheaf Theory. Still my suggestion would **Sheaf Theory by B. R. Tennison**. It is a 163 page book. But just for the introduction to sheaf you can just read the first two chapters of it, which is some 30 pages. The book is self content. It is very detailed (For example, he defines inductive limit in order to define stalk of a sheaf at a point).

Answer (score 3):

One relatively old but classic reference is Serre's paper "Faisceaux Algébriques Cohérents", often referred to simply as FAC. English translations can be found fairly easily online (see for instance [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14404/serres-fac-in-english)).

Another reference is the book *The Geometry of Schemes* by Eisenbud and Harris. They cover sheaves before moving on to schemes.

Comment: Eisenbud has a great intro section a few pages in.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Mumford and Oda - *Algebraic Geometry II* [(a penultimate draft)](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/AGII.pdf), the appendix at the first chapter; so one finds again the style of Mumford.